# How to save aws ec2 creation steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS free tier. When I create ec2 instance in ubuntu with mysql postgre anaconda vnc and other tools for data engineering. is there any way I can save scripts so next time I can run it, it is easier to create ec2 instance. I mean every step. I have to drop ec2 instance and re create.

Please advice me of possible ways to do this.

Comment: Yes, create CloudFormation template to always deploy the same ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to automate the installation steps, you can use EC2 user data  to run a shell script - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

If you want to set up a more complex environment, CloudFormation or Terraform would be a better option.